# Is an Asynchronous API Call (Parse) just using GCD? iOS

Tags: ios, asynchronous, parse-platform, grand-central-dispatch

Just as the title asks...

Does an Asynchronous API call, like in the Parse API for iOS, just put that call on a new thread (using GCD) so that it does it "in the background"?

If this is the case then I would assume that a Synchronous API call remains on the current thread.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr it's up to developer with some exceptions

First of all, you don't control threads via GCD, you are putting a task on queues.

> Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) is a technology developed by Apple Inc. to optimize application support for systems with multi-core processors and other symmetric multiprocessing systems. It is an implementation of task parallelism based on the thread pool pattern. The fundamental idea is to move the management of the thread pool out of the hands of the developer, and closer to the operating system. The developer injects "work packages" into the pool oblivious of the pool's architecture. This model improves simplicity, portability and performance.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch)

Second, what do you mean by **API**? I suppose that you wanted to say **REST API**. Another assumption is that you mean **native SDK** for REST API service, because if you implement it by yourself via networking library then you are in charge for this. As I can see from my over 3 years of experience **in iOS all calls to any method are synchronous by default**, it's a developer responsibility to place them to another queue via GCD or NSOperationQueue or whatever.

Please don't be confused by presence of completion block argument at the end of a API call. In general case **you are also responsible for making sure any update of the UI are made in main queue**, because by default this block is executed not in main queue, you may want to make some manipulation on the data you have acquired from server, e.g. sort, convert to another type, etc.

There is only few exceptions of SDKs that put a whole completion block on the main queue, e.g. AFNetworking or Parse. But in this cases SDK vendors do provide information about this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it uses the same priority or operation queue as the call was made from. For example, when making a Parse API call on the main thread, you will often get a warning about long running operations the main thread.

I would not assume this is the case for all API calls, as the library wrapper around the api call could be using it's own private operation queue in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. It can be on another operation queue with different dispatch priority

Answer (score 0):

It will be on another thread, as seen by the open source code. It uses locks and @synchronize tags to make sure that everything ends up meeting up in the end for the blocks, etc.